# geom_tile() vs. geom_point() in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am a beginner in R and using online help to understand how `ggplot2` works. So far, it's been an uphill battle. I'd appreciate your thoughts on distinction between `geom_point()` and `geom_tile()`

The issue that I am facing that my `geom_point()` and `geom_tile()` are significantly different.

Here's my plot using `geom_point()`:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:5)
 p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, 1)) + geom_point()
 p
```

This nicely plots five dots at y=5.

Now, when I use `geom_tile()`, I see that the tiles go from 0.5 to 1.5 on the y-axis. Is this expected behavior?

HEre's my code:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:5)
 p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, 1)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = x), colour = "white")
 p
```

I am a little confused. I'd have expected tiles to go from 0 to 1.

I read `?geom_tile()` to analyze this. The official documentation states *"geom_tile uses the center of the tile and its size (x, y, width, height)"* I am not quite sure what this means. How do I set and get the default value of width and height? From the above graph, it seems that the default value is 0.5 for x- and y-axis.

I'd appreciate any thoughts. I am a beginner so I'm sorry if my query is too basic.

Comment: I think the first example was supposed to use `geom_point` instead of `geom_tile`. `geom_tile` is assuming a height of 1. To adjust the height, assign another value either as an aesthetic (for a variable, e.g. `ggplot(df, aes(x, 1)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = x, height = x), colour = "white")`) or a parameter (for a fixed value, e.g. `ggplot(df, aes(x, 1)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = x), colour = "white", height = 2)`).

Comment: @alistaire Thanks. I did fix the code for geom_point(). That was a copy-paste error. Sorry about this. Your code works well...

Answer (score 0):

As Alistaire has pointed out--the fix is to change the height.

For example:

```
`ggplot(df, aes(x, 1)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = x), colour = "white", height = 0.5)`
```

This would plot tiles of height 0.5 and centered at 1. It seems the default height is 1.

Alternatively,

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, 1)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = x,height = x), colour = "white")
```

would plot a screw-thread shaped graph. The height would increase as a function of x.